# Is "to split up" or "to break up" colloquial?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, colloquialisms

Are "to split up" and "to break up" colloquial if I want to say that somebody ended a relationship?

If they are colloquial, could you give me non-colloquial synonyms except "to end" a relationship?

Comment: Breakup isn't colloquial. Read the Wikipedia article on Breakup. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakup

Comment: What do dictionaries (which usually say when an expression is a colloquialism) and thesauri say?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  My dictionary says that to split up with somebody is colloquial but there are no notes about to break up and to split up

Comment: Try 'split + meaning' and' "split up" + meaning' on Google, looking at the senses Collins gives (use double inverted commas around the latter, and choose the freedictionary link). Collins is more reliable than many dictionaries.

Comment: They're both phrasal verbs (with the same completive sense of _up_) and they can both be used as intransitive conjunctive inchoative predicates (_Bill and Mary broke/split up_) or as intransitive volitional active predicates (_Mary split/broke up with Bill_). Note that both verbs use _with_, not _from_, as the semantics might indicate. And note that there are homophonous transitive causative phrasal verbs (_Frank broke/split Bill and Mary up_). No big difference in meaning, except that _break up_ is more often used to refer to a more casual bonding than _split up_, which smells of divorce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, talking about relationships is usually done in a colloquial context. To give an account of your sentimental life to your boss or in a job-interview doesn't seem right. Why would you want a formal expression to that?

[Totally OFF-TOPIC] I always wanted to use the following word but never found the right context:

> defenestration [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defenestration)
>
> > defenestrate. *transitive verb*

From my perspective, whenever a break up occurs someone ends up defenestrated, i.e., trowed out of the window. [End of OFF-TOPIC]

Answering to your question, other meanings of the phrasal verb *brake up* can be used, for example: DIVIDE or DISPERSE; but these don't sound quite right.

> After our last big fight, we divided. [Not necessarily a relationship.]
>
> After our last big fight, we dispersed. [The fighting party was dismembered.]

OR

> After our last big fight, we parted ways. [More suitable for an ending friendship, in my opinion.]

Comment: You're right. You would probably not say it to your boss nor would you use it in a letter of application. But I have to write it in a summary of a book I have to read. This summary needs to be formal and this book is about breaking up. This is the reason why I have to choose non-colloquial one but break up sounds colloquial for me and in my native language as well. Anyway. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you more. And using "to end the relationship" seem totally formal to me. Cheers!